# Sharing Links across multiple sites

Tags: gratis, hyperlink

Currently using either Jetpack or SharePress, I can share out a link to a site using my Wordpress blog after making a post about it. That isn't very useful; most links are time-sensitive (e.g., news) or are controversial (e.g., political) so wouldn't make much sense sharing on my blog. I was wondering if there was a way to share on multiple sites simultaneously with one button. I have addthis installed, but I don't see the point as I still need to share it to each individual site sequentially (not really much different than pasting the URL).

Requirements:

- free
- web-based or browser plugin (Chrome)
- Somewhat consistent appearance across multiple endpoints (this actually depends mainly on Facebook Open Graph and Twitter Cards, not the extension, but some, if any, sharing functionality should be consistent if it is generated by the app)
- Support for: Facebook, Twitter, Google Plus
- Optional support for: Tumblr, Pinterest, StumbleUpon, Wordpress custom-hosted blog

Comment: As a Wordpress plugin? or as a browser plugin? or ?

Comment: I'm looking to post from either a website or within the browser (be it plugin or bookmarklet) to the sites listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently came across [Path](https://path.com) - which can share with Facebook, Twitter, Foursquare, Tumblr, and has a Wordpress connector. I can also share from Wordpress to Path with Jetpack, so I do idly wonder if I can make it go into infinite recursion.

Can't do Google Plus, but currently, while I think some features of G+ is cool (being able to "like" pages without following them, circles, hangouts) none of my friends use it who aren't already on Facebook.

As for Pinterest, that's delegated to more specialized types of sharing.

Lastly, for Stumbleupon - well I don't really ever get bored/unbusy enough to use it, so I could care less.

The only real disadvantage to Path is it doesn't have a true web interface (only for about / company information, signup, and account management), bookmarklet or browser plugin. It's main functionality is a mobile app, so if I'm trying to share something from my desktop it can be slightly cumbersome. I'm sure it's in the works though, since it's fairly new.